# Are multiple values possible in a switch statement?

Tags: java

```
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Which file would you like to test?");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter '1' for life1");
            System.out.println("Enter '2' for life2");
            System.out.println("Enter '3' for life3");
            System.out.println("Enter '4' for life4");
            System.out.println("Enter '5' for life5");
            kb.nextInt();
            int one, two, three, four, five;
            one = 1; two = 2; three = 3; four = 4; five = 5;
            switch(one || two || three || four || five){
            case 1:{
                GameOfLife gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life1.txt");
                gol.print("Input/life1.txt");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the following code example that I am working with. Basically what I would like this to do is evaluate what the user enters from the keyboard, and then instantiate the GameOfLife class and the respective text file to print on the screen. After this, the user would then be prompted to update the file or not with the next iteration. I'm not sure why this is not working the way I'd like it to, I thought my reasoning and logic was sound.

Comment: `one || two || three || four || five` is an invalid expression. What are you trying to do in that switch statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you wanted to initialize your `gol` variable based on the value (and you don't really need an or, and your switch cases need to be constants) like

```
GameOfLife gol = null;
final int one = 1, two = 2, three = 3, four = 4, five = 5;
switch (test) {
case one:
    gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life1.txt");
    gol.print("Input/life1.txt");
    break;
case two:
    gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life2.txt");
    gol.print("Input/life2.txt");
    break;
case three:
    gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life3.txt");
    gol.print("Input/life3.txt");
    break;
case four:
    gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life4.txt");
    gol.print("Input/life4.txt");
    break;
case five:
    gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life5.txt");
    gol.print("Input/life5.txt");
    break;
}
```

But, I think that was really supposed to look like

```
GameOfLife gol = null;
final int one = 1, two = 2, three = 3, four = 4, five = 5;
switch (test) {
case one:
    gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life1.txt");
    break;
case two:
    gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life2.txt");
    break;
case three:
    gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life3.txt");
    break;
case four:
    gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life4.txt");
    break;
case five:
    gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life5.txt");
    break;
}
if (gol != null) {
  gol.print();
} else {
  System.err.println("error: no such GameOfLife " + test);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the fall-though case

```
int value = keyboard.nextInt();
switch (value) {
      case ONE:
      case TWO:
      case THREE:
      ...
}
```

Please read [The switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) as a general guide to the format of this construct

Comment: Thanks for the input Reimeus, I've been working on this issue for a couple of hours now and I wasn't seeing it quite clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Swith allows put several cases in a row, but not in the switch:

```
    final int a = 5;
    switch (a) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        // do something
        break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
        // do something
        break;
    default:
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

int one, two, three, four, five;

First make a variable, where you will store your value.

Something like this:

```
int value;
```

Let's say that the value can go from 1-5.

```
int value = 2;
```

And now, depending on the value, we wont to do something with it:

```
switch(value){

    case 1:
            GameOfLife gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life1.txt");
            gol.print("Input/life1.txt");
    break;

    case 2:
            GameOfLife gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life2.txt");
            gol.print("Input/life2.txt");
    break;

    ...

    case 5:
            GameOfLife gol = new GameOfLife("Input/life5.txt");
            gol.print("Input/life5.txt");
    break;
        }
```

You can also add the case if nothing of the previous was true...if somehow, your value is >5

```
default: 
   //do something
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better if you ask the user to enter a choice then switch the choice variable. U can also use the switch construct to then create the objects in all cases or use a fall through switch construct (don't write break).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you dont need that lot of variables, just one that will receive the user's input. As @Reimeus said, you use that single variable in the switch() sintax and go through the various possible cases for that variable.
So:

```
int value = kb.nextInt() (I dont know this Scanner class, I just assume this is correct)
switch(value){
 case 1:
 //do something
 break;
 case 2:
//do something
break;
 case 3:
 case 4:
   //do something - in this case, both cases value=3 and value=4 will respond equally, until a BREAK command if found;
   break;
 default:
  //do something in the case that tha value of "value" did not fall into any of the previous cases.
}
```